# What is this weird upside down U shaped pipline for?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image: Strange upside u shaped piping]

There is this tall upside down shaped U pipe near a sugar refinery on Maui and I can't figure out what it's for ? I've also see these in other industrial areas near salt flats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of these diversions in a natural gas line?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/569/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-diversions-in-a-natural-gas-line/577#577)

Comment: Some are designed to absorb expansion or contraction of the pipe as it changes temperature.

Comment: @SolarMike But those tend to be only a few feet diversion. This is too narrow and tall for it to be that IMO.

Comment: Yes, I think expansion joints like this are often shorter in relation to the total length in a given direction. I wonder of this is a pneumatic conveying line. I cannot think of a reason for this configuration. I wonder if it is to increase residence time for a conveying operation, maybe to remove moisture? This is just a guess.